# HTML not 100% left

Tags: html, css

My black box in this example should be all the way to the left and all the way up. I don't want to see any white space left or above of it.

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

But that isnt the case! Can anyone tell me how I can achive this?

Comment: You should set padding and margin for html and body to 0. Normally, I will use css reset tool before starting a project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most major browsers, the default margin is `8px` on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the `user-agent-stylesheet` your browser provides.

You need to give `margin:0` to body like this

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>
<style>
  #box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>
```

**P.S** Also set padding to 0 for both html and body

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `0 margin` to `body and html` as well

```css
body, html{
margin:0;
}
#box{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to remove the default  margin on the body element.

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```